# vue 3 Property '...' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async showMore(parentId) {
            if (this.isLoading) return;
            this.isLoading = true;
            await this.someAction({ parentId });
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code give error: Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `defineComponent` wrapper

```
export default defineComponent({
    ...
});
```